# Query to retrieve count per hour and zero if none

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying all the ways, but I am not successful so far.

I have my data in the below way. I am using postGreSQL

```
order_id |      create_date
    -----+--------------------
    6000 | 2013-05-09 11:53:04
    6001 | 2013-05-09 12:58:00
    6002 | 2013-05-09 13:01:08
    6003 | 2013-05-09 13:01:32
    6004 | 2013-05-09 14:05:06
    6005 | 2013-05-09 14:06:25
    6006 | 2013-05-09 14:59:58
    6007 | 2013-05-09 19:00:07
```

I need a query which produces the count of orders per hour for all the 24 hours. If there are no orders in an hour, query output should be zero by default. Below should be the output format.

```
    orders |      hour
    -----+--------------------
    0    | 00:00
    0    | 01:00
    0    | 02:00
    0    | 03:00
    0    | 04:00
    0    | 05:00
    0    | 06:00
    0    | 07:00
    0    | 08:00
    0    | 09:00
    0    | 10:00
    1    | 11:00
    1    | 12:00
    2    | 13:00
    3    | 14:00
    0    | 15:00
    0    | 16:00
    0    | 17:00
    0    | 18:00
    1    | 19:00
    0    | 20:00
    0    | 21:00
    0    | 22:00
    0    | 23:00
```

Is it possible to do? Below is my current query. Ofcourse it is not giving the output in the way that I desire.

```
select count(order_id) as orders, date_trunc('hour', create_date) as hr from order_table where date_trunc('day', create_date)='2013-05-09' GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', create_date);
```

Comment: On which DBMS are you working? MySQL or PostgreSQL? Also, can you please post the table schema?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: This may help. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Comment: @O.Jones It's not mysql, it's postgresql

Comment: I closed the question while it still had a MySQL tag. I've nominated it for reopening. Others can do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the hours.  Here is one method using `generate_series()`:

```
select '00:00'::time + g.h * interval '1 hour',
       count(order_id) as orders
from generate_series(0, 23, 1) g(h) left join
     order_table ot
     on extract(hour from create_date) = g.h and
        date_trunc('day', create_date) = '2013-05-09'
group by g.h
order by g.h;
```

Or alternatively:

```
select g.dte, count(order_id) as orders
from generate_series('2013-05-09'::timestamp, '2013-05-09 23:00:00'::timestamp, interval '1 hour') g(dte) left join
     order_table ot
     on g.dte = date_trunc('hour', create_date) 
group by g.dte
order by g.dte;
```

Comment: In the first query output, the hour column have the output format as "01:00:00". How can we change it to "01:00"?

Comment: First answer give the exact what in the question for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a numbers CTE (Postgresql example):

```
with Nums(NN) as
(
values(0)
union all
select NN+1
where NN <23
)
select NN as the_hour, count(order_id) as orders
from Nums
left join order_table
on date_part('hour',create_date) = NN
group by NN
```

Comment: It is giving me an error like "column "nn" does not exist". Do I need to replace NN with date every where?

Answer (score 0):

Can I still give an answer? Test, test, oh yes it works. Ok, I think the problem in your query is that your comparison is wrong: `date_trunc('day', create_date)='2013-05-09'` should be: `date_trunc('day', create_date)='2013-05-09 00:00:00'`. So like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) as orders, 
       date_trunc('hour',create_date) as hr 
FROM order_table 
WHERE date_trunc('day', create_date) = '2013-05-09 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour',create_date);
```

This does however not returns zero counts, but others have solved that problem.