# How to fix SQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" Position: 15?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get data as mentioned follwing question.

[Query to retrieve count per hour and zero if none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535931/query-to-retrieve-count-per-hour-and-zero-if-none)

So according to that, I execute the following query in Postgresql so it is working fine.

```
select '00:00'::time + g.h * interval '1 hour',count(sv.id) as orders from generate_series(0, 23, 1) g(h) left join paymentvirtualization.summery_virtualizer sv on extract(hour from sv.last_updated) = g.h and date_trunc('day', sv.last_updated) = '2019-10-11' group by g.h order by g.h;
```

But my problem is I want this to execute as a spring data JPA native query like.

```
  @Query(
            value = "select '00:00'::time + g.h * interval '1 hour',count(sv.id) as orders from generate_series(0, 23, 1) g(h) left join paymentvirtualization.summery_virtualizer sv on extract(hour from sv.last_updated) = g.h and date_trunc('day', sv.last_updated) = '2019-10-11' group by g.h order by g.h",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Map<String, Integer>> getPaymentDistry();
```

If I execute it I am getting an error like

```
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
```

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The obfuscation layer chokes on the `::` because it uses `:` to introduce named parameter. Typically the solution is to use the standard compliant `cast()` operator instead.

```
select cast('00:00' as time) + g.h * interval '1 hour' ...
```

alternatively use the ANSI time syntax as suggested by Laurenz:

```
select time '00:00' + g.h * interval '1 hour' ...
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: very good point, I have amended the answer.